# Two errors with conflict solutions

Tags: java, mysql, gwt, blob, code-access-security

I am not good at GWT. 
I connected my eclipse to hosting server database through Database development perspective successfully.  I am able to see tables of my hosting database from the eclipse window.   I then tried to run Blob Example program in following blog.(code is same)

http://www.fishbonecloud.com/2010/12/tutorial-gwt-application-for-storing.html

here in getPicture() method of BlobServiceImpl, I tried to store 'l' value to my hosting database table.

```
 public Picture getPicture(String id) {

long l = Long.parseLong(id);
Picture picture = ofy.get(Picture.class, l);
PreparedStatement imageURLstmt = null;
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

     Connection userregcon =      DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://69.162.121.114:3306/ayushcar_AyushCareDB?"
              + "user=xxxx&password=yyyyy");
    /*Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection userregcon=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:AyushCare_DSN");*/

     String stmt = "update UserProfilesTable2 set ImageURL=?";System.out.println("Ima1:"+l);
     imageURLstmt = userregcon.prepareStatement(stmt);System.out.println("Ima2");
    imageURLstmt.setString(1,String.valueOf(l) );System.out.println("Ima3");
     @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    int execute = imageURLstmt.executeUpdate(); System.out.println("Ima4");




     System.out.println("Image insertion   status:"+imageURLstmt.getUpdateCount());
}
```

but I am getting following error:

```
Jul 10, 2013 6:12:30 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService init
INFO: Local Datastore initialized: 
Type: High Replication
Storage: E:\sireesha\ProjectWorkSpace\BlobExample\war\WEB-INF\appengine- generated\local_db.bin
Jul 10, 2013 6:12:30 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService  load
INFO: Time to load datastore: 410 ms
Jul 10, 2013 6:12:33 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract    blob.example.client.Picture blob.example.client.BlobService.getPicture(java.lang.String)'     threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
at      com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:106)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:421)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
  Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at blob.example.server.BlobServiceImpl.getPicture(BlobServiceImpl.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
... 38 more
 Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:289)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:314)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.init(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.<init>(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:33)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.<clinit>(NonRegisteringDriver.java:117)
... 47 more

com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 500 The call failed on the server; see server log for details
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:209)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:258)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
***********************************
```

hear i got two errors

- `java.security.AccessControlException:` access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
- `com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException:` 500 The call failed on the server; see server log for details

For the first one I searched solution in google. It says, turnoff google app engine.  So I turned off through project properties.

After that i runs like RunAs->web application.
It used jetty log service. just i turned off GAE. again i runs like in normal way..Run as->web application. That's only i did. it is running on GWT code server.

in URL of web browser, so i think, it is running on GWT code server. But after this i tried that, i created BlobExample.war and deployed in local tomcat server through manager. even it doesnt work. console showing WARn like this:

```
 [WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract     java.lang.String blob.example.client.BlobService.getBlobStoreUploadUrl()' threw an     unexpected exception: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'blobstore' or call 'CreateUploadURL()' was not found.
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package     'blobstore' or call 'CreateUploadURL()' was not found.
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:100)
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:55)
at      com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceImpl.createUploadUrl(BlobstoreServiceImpl.java:68)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceImpl.createUploadUrl(BlobstoreServiceImpl.java:43)
at     blob.example.server.BlobServiceImpl.getBlobStoreUploadUrl(BlobServiceImpl.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
... 22 more
ERROR: 500 - POST /blobexample/blobservice (127.0.0.1) 57 bytes
 Request headers
  Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
  Connection: keep-alive
  Accept: */*
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)             Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36
  Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
  Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
  Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
  Content-Length: 138
  X-GWT-Module-Base: http://127.0.0.1:8888/blobexample/
  X-GWT-Permutation: HostedMode
  Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8888
  Content-Type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8
  Response headers
  Content-Type: text/plain
```

tomcat Server log file show error:

```
Jul 11, 2013 12:22:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 11, 2013 12:22:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 11, 2013 12:22:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache',  'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@11013d6')
Jul 11, 2013 12:27:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet blobServlet as unavailable
Jul 11, 2013 12:27:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet blobServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: blob.example.server.BlobServiceImpl
at     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

so hear, server unable to find BlobServiceImpl in inside package.
My web.xml file code is:

```
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>blobServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>blob.example.server.BlobServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

 <servlet>
<servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>blob.example.server.UploadServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>blobServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/blobexample/blobservice</url-pattern>
```

```
  <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/blobexample/uploadservice</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

i am posting localhost_accesess_log file in server:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2013:12:22:42 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11444
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2013:12:22:49 +0530] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 401 2550
127.0.0.1 - root [11/Jul/2013:12:23:01 +0530] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 200 20917
127.0.0.1 - root [11/Jul/2013:12:23:16 +0530] "POST /manager/html/undeploy?        path=/BlobExample&org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=B32B69B40BCFB089A470FBFBDEC8F263 HTTP/1.1" 200 19247
127.0.0.1 - root [11/Jul/2013:12:27:07 +0530] "POST /manager/html/upload?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=F1E8DF0FA23DE56DF7C794EDED7DE094 HTTP/1.1" 200 20917
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2013:12:27:23 +0530] "GET /BlobExample HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2013:12:27:23 +0530] "GET /BlobExample/ HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2013:12:27:23 +0530] "GET /BlobExample/blobexample/blobexample.nocache.js HTTP/1.1" 200 7212
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2013:12:27:24 +0530] "GET /BlobExample/blobexample/EDB6C692B33D6F87EC48FBD829DCDC98.cache.html HTTP/1.1" 200 113731
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2013:12:27:40 +0530] "POST /BlobExample/blobexample/blobservice HTTP/1.1" 500 3190
```

i understood error hear. My server side program not accessible to server. but it is WAR file having raw files in output folder. so i cant change.

I am using Eclipse-JUNO 4.2 version, JRE6, SDK 1.6(our hosting server is using this. so), GWT 2.5.1. where i can see server log in eclipse. Is it need any plugin?
If any one give best answer for my problem, thanks to them in advance.

Comment: On which webserver are you going to deploy the application? tomcat? jetty? something else? It's not going to be google app engine I guess, so you should not switch google app engine on, certainly not to fix problems and you can't use google app engine specific libraries either. Also add some source code to show that might help in identifying the cause.

Comment: well. i too got doubt where i am running my gwt application in eclipse  IDE? just i turned off GAE. again i runs like in normal way..Run as->web application